# Sort and count number of occurrence of part of a filename with "ls"

Tags: bash, sorting, unix, ls, uniq

I want count the number of occurrences of part of a filename when doing ls.

For example if my directory has the following files:

```
apple.cool_test1
banana.cool_test1
banana.cool_test2
cherry.cool_test1
cherry.cool_test2
cherry.cool_test3
```

I want the result like this:

```
1 apple 
2 banana
3 cherry
```

So I tried `"ls | sort | uniq -c"` but how do I extract the first part of the filename.  My record separator can be "." ?

Comment: Is it possible that you have more than one dot per line? E.g. `apple.cool.test1`

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 2):

give this one-liner a try:

```
$  awk -F'.' '{a[$1]++}END{for(x in a)print a[x],x}' file  
1 apple
2 banana
3 cherry
```

Comment: Works !! Thank you :)))

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the first part with `cut` or `awk`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' * | cut -d'.' -f1 | uniq -c
      1 apple
      2 banana
      3 cherry
$ printf '%s\n' * | awk -F'.' '{print $1}' | uniq -c
      1 apple
      2 banana
      3 cherry
```